# how to remove same characters from a huge string using method in java

Tags: java, string, methods

I have a string of 10^1000 characters.where we cant run a loop to check one by one..then what should i do?

i do like

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = new String("abbc");
    String output = new String();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < output.length(); j++) {
            if (input.charAt(i) != output.charAt(j)) {
                output = output + input.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(output);

}
}
```

I do it in this way to remove the all duplicate character from a string .but it is not efficient when the input.length() is too large.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ? Can you give an example with a short string ?

Comment: You should use BigDecimal

Comment: `now enter code here`- did you copy this text directly from some quiz?

Comment: have you tried it with recursion

Comment: 'enter code here' ... yeah, that's not going to happen

Comment: let i do it in this way to remove the all duplicate character from a string

Comment: ublic class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = new String("abbc");
        String output = new String();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < output.length(); j++) {
                if (input.charAt(i) != output.charAt(j)) {
                    output = output + input.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(output);

    }

}

Comment: that should be in the question, not in a comment

Comment: have you ever heard of the 'contains(..)' method?

Comment: I doubt that your laptop can hold Strings of that size in memory, as the known universe contains of only (estimated) 10^78 atoms...

Comment: As Gyro already said, the 10^1000 is not at all plausible. Don't write things if you don't know what they mean. And don't ask us for efficiency while you're still struggling with correctness. Your program prints an empty string, and that's definitely wrong. You never tried even small inputs, did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maintain a set of characters (`Set<Character>`) you already did encounter for 0 .. (i-1).

As this reeks of homework I leave it to that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to convert the string to an array of char, and store it in a LinkedHashSet. That will preserve your ordering, and remove duplicates

```
char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
Set<Character> charSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
for (char c : chars) {
    charSet.add(c);
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Character character : charSet) {
    sb.append(character);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Is it run on IDE?

Comment: sure, put this code in `main()` method or create another method and call it in `main()`

Answer (score 2):

If your String has separator I think that you could use a Set.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(text.split(" ")));
```

Or in java 8:

```
Set<String> set = Arrays.stream(text.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```